# react-native mount all components on componentDidMount

Tags: react-native, components, mount

I have a question about react-native. How to mount all components when initial route has loaded? Im using drawer navigator of react-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're referring to is called lazy loading in React Navigation. When lazy loading is enabled, the screens are mounted only once you navigate to them. Unfortunately, the only navigator that supports disabling lazy loading is TabNavigator. As far as I know, old versions of React Navigation v1 (I believe prior to v1.1) did not have lazy loading, but it's probably not the best idea to downgrade all the way to v1.0. Alternatively, you could switch to using TabNavigator, hide the tab bar with `navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false }`, then build and display your own drawer.